# Select count from four tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

I have four tables

1. companies (fields: id, name)
2. cities (fields: id, name)
3. categories (fields: id, name)
4. city_category_company (fields: company_id, city_id, category_id)

I need to count amount of companies in each category on city page.

Now, I do it in so ugly cycle

```
$q = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `categories`");
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $r2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(
        mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(`company_id`) AS `num` FROM `city_category_company` WHERE `city_id` = '{$city['id']}' AND `category_id` = '{$r['id']}'")
    );
}
```

But if I have many categories, it becomes very many queries to database on one page (50 or more). Please, help me to optimize query

Comment: You can use GROUP BY category_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(ccc.company_id) AS num
FROM city_category_company ccc
INNER JOIN categories c ON ccc.category_id = cc.id
WHERE ccc.city_id={city_id}
GROUP BY c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(co.id) AS company_count, cc.category_id, ca.name AS category_name 
FROM companies co 
INNER JOIN city_category_company cc ON co.id=cc.company_id 
INNER JOIN categories ca ON ca.id=cc.category_id 
GROUP BY cc.category_id, ca.name
```